# Alpha numeric lower case case and "-" ,

Tags: c#, regex

I want to do validation that user enter only the  following:

1. Alpha numeric `a to z` with lower case only.
2. Can contain  hyphen `‘-’` but not start or end with it.
3. Can contain  `'.'` but not start or end with it.
4. Can have space at the end.

I try with the following but its not working,any Idea how to change it?

```
"^[a-z0-9]+(\.-[a-z0-9]+)*$"
```

Comment: Please make sure your syntax is consistent. If that is a C# string (as implied by the quotation marks), the backslash probably needs to be duplicated. If it is the regex itself, remove the quotation marks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^[a-z\d][\da-z-.]*[a-z\s\d]$
```

`^[a-z\d]` means start with a-z or a digit.

Then

`[\da-z-.]*` means match 0 or more digit, a-z, hyphen and dot

And

`[a-z\s\d]$` means it allows only a-z or a digit or space.

Comment: An answer for mindless copy and pasting without any explanation may help the OP in this particular case, but it will probably not help them understand how to generally solve this kind of problem, and less so will it help any future visitors with similar, yet not exactly the same problem.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, if you have citation of copy pasting, then comment, about it. Else, don't. Also, I'll include explanation

Comment: I do not understand your comment, can you rephrase? What do you mean by "citation of copy pasting"?

Comment: By the way, while I agree the question is vague about that, your suggested regex requires the matched string to have a minimum length of three characters, which is not a restriction contained in the question.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper By citation of copy pasting, I mean, that I didn't copy it from somewhere else. It is my regex ;)

Comment: @AmitJoki: I think what was meant was that the OP would copy and paste your answer without learning anything, not that you copied it from somewhere.

Comment: Thanks Amit Voted up,one issue is that you need to type 3 char at least how can I change it to two ?

Comment: Ooh, I see, I didn't mean to imply that. I was rather concerned that the *question author* would copy and paste your regex without understanding what they are doing.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, oh! Sorry. I'm not a native English speaker. I thought you were referring to me. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

shopia, you can do something like this:

```
bool isValid = false;
try {
    isValid = Regex.IsMatch(s1, @"^[a-z\d][-.a-z\d]* ?(?<![-.])$");
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // some syntax error
}
```

Here are the tokens that the engine tries to match from left to right as it reads the string from left to right.

1. The `^` asserts that we are at the beginning of the string.
2. The `[a-z\d]` character class matches one letter or digit.
3. The `[-.a-z\d]` matches one dash, dot, letter or digit, and the `*` makes this happen zero or more times.
4. The  `?` (note the space before the question mark) allows for a space at the end
5. The `(?<![-.])` is a negative lookbehind asserting that at this position in the string, we are not immediately preceded by a dash or a dot
6. The `$` asserts that we are at the end of the string.

Please note that it is not entirely clear whether you will allow a dot or dash before the optional space character. I have assumed that the answer is yes, because in `abcd-` the dash is not at the end of the string. However if you do not want to allow that character even before the dash, just move the negative lookbehind, so that your regex becomes:

```
^[a-z\d][-.a-z\d]*(?<![-.]) ?$
```

Comment: missing the digits - added

Comment: Tomas, care to let me know why you rolled back my edit? at least let me know if I've done something wrong.